# Copy features from feature class to an existing feature class with arcpy

Tags: arcpy, features, feature-class, copy

I see CopyFeatures_management, but this creates a new feature class.

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000035000000

Is there a way to copy features from a feature class into an existing feature class?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to use the [Append_Management](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Append/001700000050000000/) tool.

If you know the attribute tables will match up (including data type), use `schema_type` `NO_TEST` anyway (even though the documentation would suggest `TEST`).
If the attribute tables do not match up you will have to deal with field mappings, which can be a huge pain in arcpy.
(If you are using `NO_TEST` and a subtype, make sure that you pass in `None` for the `field_mapping` argument.)

Answer (score 1):

You can combine search cursor and insert cursor. It can be used to avoid field_mappings.

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/searchcursor-class.htm
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/insertcursor-class.htm

```
    # check if pasted feature have common fields
    to_paste_fields_names = [field.name for field in arcpy.ListFields(shape_to_paste)]
    base_shape_fields_names = [field.name for field in arcpy.ListFields(base_shape)]
    fields_names = sorted(set(base_shape_fields_names) & set(to_paste_fields_names))
    if len(fields_names) > 0:
        # start search cursor on shape to paste
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(shape_to_paste, fields_names) as cursor:
            # start insert cursor on base shape
            with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(base_shape, fields_names) as insert_cursor:
                # iterate through search cursor
                for row in cursor:
                    insert_cursor.insertRow(row)
```